# High Resolution Monthly or Annual Precipitation data for four corner states or the Navajo Nation

Tags: precipitation

I was wondering if anyone on here might know where I can find 30 meter resolution Average Annual or Average Monthly Precipitation data, that would cover the 4 corners area (UT, AZ, NM, CO) or basically the Navajo Nation?

I am working on a Mule Deer Habitat Suitability analysis for one of my class project's and have elevation and landcover data that is 30m resolution.

I wanted to try to do my analysis with 30m precipitation data too, from at least two different years or timeframes (i.e. 2008-2011 and 2014-2017 -OR- 2010 and 2013).

I know PRISM data is at 800m resolution, and could resize the cells to 30m, but would be great if I could use 30m precip data.

I've been looking around for a couple days now.

Comment: I don't know of any data available at that resolution. However, you might be able to downscale the data in a way that is a bit more sophisticated than simply re-sampling to 30m. See http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.488.2702&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Your question is most welcome at GIS SE too! I agree with @Nick that if you need to incorporate 30m precip data, you may be able to interpolate the data to produce 30m spatial resolution data.